# How to tell eclipse to run a perl script and pass parameters to it before building my project?

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile

I have a project in eclipse I would like to run a perl script before every build on eclipse
but I want to pass the perl script parameters, in detail I want to pass it the names/paths of all the files in the project

(this script add things to make makefile)

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As a general direction: You would use building systems like **Ant or Maven** to realise this in Eclipse.

For Ant: http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#shell-redirect-2

Comment: In what way does this answer enable someone to actually run a perl script? In my case I was actually looking for a way to have Eclipse CDT use the perl script that the particular open-source project uses.